# Is it possible to display an alert dialog on the device home screen using a Broadcast Receiver , Not on our App main activity?

Tags: java, android

I want to display an Alert-Dialog when a newly app installed, that showing what the permissions required by it,before the user install the app and see the requested permissions.

Comment: You contradict yourself in the same sentence. When will the dialog be displayed? in the play store? or when the user launches the app for the first time? If the former, you can't do it, if the latter you can create a custom dialog and have it displayed as a launcher activity, Plenty of similar questions here.

Comment: The app will run in the back ground (broadcast receiver), and the user doesn't need to run the app, the dialog will displayed independently on the device's home screen when an app installed viewing the required permissions

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't, but you can create a window that can be shown outside the app above other apps.
This will be required you to ask the user for permission: android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

For example:

```
    View view;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams;
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) MyApplication.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    boolean showing = false;
    void Create(){
        view= LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_layout,null);

        int size = 150;
        layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                size , size,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );

        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;
        layoutParams.setTitle("123");
        layoutParams.dimAmount = 0;
    }

    void show(){
        if(showing) return;

        showing = true;
        windowManager.addView(view, layoutParams);
    }

    void hide(){
        if(!showing) return;

        showing = false;
        windowManager.removeView(view);
    }
```

Comment: @Aqua760 if the answer works for you when you test it out, please consider accepting it and upvoting it!